# How do I create function to display images and play audio files randomly in Corona SDK /LUA?

Tags: arrays, image, audio, lua, coronasdk

Just recently I have started working on my application  which is a puzzle game using Corona SDK. I am new to Corona and I am looking for solution how to display images and sounds randomly. There might different images that represent different letters of the alphabet and different sounds when one of the particular letter is taped by the user. I played myself with this some time and I still dont't know how to manage with this problem. I will greatly appreciate it if someone could give me a hint or soulution as I tried to look around for similar example but, in vain, nothing works for me.

```
local function main()

display.setDefault( "background", 215, 1, 215 )

  --load sound file

 local a_letter = audio.loadSound("a_letter.wav")

  local puzzleArray = {"blockA.png", "blockB.png"} ,
  puzzle = display.newImage( puzzleArray [math.random(#puzzleArray)])
  puzzle.x = math.random( 115, display.contentWidth - 115 )
  puzzle.y = math.random( 115, display.contentHeight - 115 )
  puzzle.type = puzzleType
  puzzle.alpha = 0.5

  function puzzle: tap(event)
    if puzzle.alpha == 0 then
    transition.to(puzzle, {time = 1000, alpha=0}) 
  else
    transition.to(puzzle, {time = 150, alpha=1})  
    end
  end

   --Button press event
 local a_puzzle = function(event)
  audio.play(a_letter)
 end

  puzzle: addEventListener("tap", puzzle) 
  puzzle:addEventListener("tap", a_puzzle)

end
main()
```

This is my actual working code but in the future I would like to build levels and display words and sound for each tapped letter. I tought about associative array and tables but I am not sure how this could be doable, I hope that someone more experienced would help with. 
Regards

Comment: Hi Albert, I did try to use the example that you posted but I can't figure out how to implement this solution in my application. I could run this code without error having following structure (however none of the object are displayed): local puzzleArray = { letterA = {audio_file="pp.mp3", img="blockA.png"}, letterB = {audio_file="a_letter.wav", img="blockB.png"} , } math.randomseed(tostring(os.clock() * 1000000):reverse():sub(1, 8)) ;Could you explain bit more the last bit of code?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the same letter plays the same audio, you can use table like this:

```
local resources={
    letterA={audio_file="XXX.mp3",img="XXX.png"},
    letterB={audio_file="XXX.mp3",img="XXX.png"},...
}
```

also you can use

```
math.randomseed(tonumber(tostring(os.clock() * 1000000):reverse():sub(1, 8)) or os.time())
```

instead of

```
math.randomseed(os.time())
```